# In C++, log2() and log2l() returning different values

Tags: c++

While I was coding in C++ I stumbled upon something, the return value of `log2(n)` and `log2l(n)` are completely different for a certain value of `n` :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int d= log2l(288230376151711743);
    cout<<d;
    return 0;
}
```

This above code displays a value of 57 whereas the following code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int d= log2(288230376151711743);
    cout<<d;
    return 0;
}
```

Displays a value of `58` upon execution.

Why is this occurring can someone please explain me ?

Comment: It's probably because of different round-off errors when converting the integer to `long double` versus `double`.

Comment: One is rounding down, the other rounds up.

Comment: It's not because `log2` and `log2l` are returning different values, it's because floating-point operations in general may return different values if you use different operations, precisions, etc. When working with floating-point numbers, you always have to consider rounding.

Comment: Don't use `#include <bit/stdc++.h>`. It's not a standard header, and especially when you add `using namespace std;` you're setting yourself up for lots of name conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are typecasting double to integer datatype which is rounding it down.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << log2(288230376151711743) << "\n";
    cout << log2l(288230376151711743) << "\n";

    cout << (int) log2(288230376151711743) << "\n";
    cout << (int) log2l(288230376151711743) << "\n";

    cout << (long) log2(288230376151711743) << "\n";
    cout << (long) log2l(288230376151711743) << "\n";

    cout << (double) log2(288230376151711743) << "\n";
    cout << (double) log2l(288230376151711743) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

try to run this code and observe the results.
[log2 docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/log2/)

Comment: Re: "It's because you are typecasting double to integer" -- there are no casts in the original code. The problem is that the code **converts** double to integer. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Comment: Don't use `#include <bit/stdc++.h>`. It's not a standard header, and especially when you add `using namespace std;` you're setting yourself up for lots of name conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following expression for do-it-yourself:

```
auto log2 = log2(288230376151711743); // log2 => double | log2l() => long double
```

You'll get to know that variable `d` is a datatype set to `double`, again if you do the same thing with `log2l()`, you'll find that `d` is set to `long double`, i.e. the function `log2l()` returns a `long double`, but the value is rounding down while typecasting **implicitly** from a `long double` into `int`.

That's why, it'll show `58` for `log2()`. And in contrary, `57` for `log2l()` when the variable is an integer.

Comment: Re: "the value is rounding down while typecasting from a `long double` into `int`" -- there are no casts in the original code. The problem is that the code **converts** `long double` to `int`. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion

Comment: Casts are **always** explicit. **Conversions** can be explicit (i.e., casts) or implicit (as in the code in question).